# open a dBase table

Tags: delphi, dbase

I have to copy some information from an old dBase database using ADOConnection and AdoTable. I am able to open all tables but I get this exception

> Data provider or other service
>   returned an E_FAIL status

while trying to open a big table 1.01 GB (1 093 588 624 bytes).  I note that the performance is very bad. this is the connection string

```
  ConnectionString:=Format('Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=%s;Extended Properties=dBase IV;',[path])
```

Comment: I know it's deprecated, but have you tried opening using BDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the default setting for `CursorLocation` with TADOConnection is `clUseClient`. With that setting, the entire data set is read into memory by the client.  That would explain the slowness and may explain the error.

Try changing it to `clUseServer`.

```
ADOConn.CursorLocation := clUseServer;
```

Or you can change it in the object inspector properties.

Comment: @Najem:  It may be looking for a primary key for being able to make updates.  I'm just guessing here, but maybe try a different cursor type on the table (possibly ctKeyset or ctStatic).

Comment: the performance has improved after changing the cursor type to clUseServer. and the whole 5746353 recorders loaded

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it's got an autoopen (.MDX) index flag in the header, but the index doesn't exist in the database.

You can try this - it clears that autoopen flag in the database header. **USE A COPY OF THE DATABASE TO TEST ON!!!** I haven't tested on DBase IV, but it works on several flavors of FoxPro and DBase.

```
procedure FixDBFHeader(const FileName: string);
var
  ByteRead: Byte;
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    // Byte offset 28 has a value of 0x01 if a structural (auto-open) index exists,
    // or 0x00 if no such index exists. If the value is not set, we do nothing.
    Stream.Position := 28;
    Stream.Read(ByteRead, SizeOf(ByteRead));
    if ByteRead = 1 then
    begin
      ByteRead := 0;
      Stream.Position := 28;
      Stream.Write(ByteRead, SizeOf(Byte));
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

After clearing that flag in the header, you should be able to open the .DBF with ADO or [Advantage Database Server](http://advantagedatabaseserver.com) - their local server is free, and supports SQL. Note that I'm not affiliated with Advantage in any way; I've just used their product to work with legacy DBF files for a long time.

Answer (score -1):

If you still have problems with TAdoConnection I would suggest [Apollo](http://www.vistasoftware.com/).  This supports many different table types (Clipper NTX, Foxpro CDX).